Scroll to Top on Route Change Not Working
I'm working on a React project where I need the page to scroll to the top when navigating to a new route. I have implemented a ScrollToTop component, but it does not seem to work. The page retains its scroll position after navigation.
Despite implementing the ScrollToTop component and verifying that the console log outputs the correct pathnames, the page does not scroll to the top on route change. The previous scroll position is retained.
Troubleshooting Steps

Verified that the console.log statement in ScrollToTop.js works and logs the correct pathnames.
Ensured that ScrollToTop is included in App.js and wraps the Routes.

Additional Info
The code can be found on my GitHub Repository
I implemented a ScrollToTop component that uses the useEffect hook to scroll to the top of the page when the pathname changes. I expected this component to reset the scroll position to the top of the page whenever the route changes.
However, despite the component being correctly placed and logging the pathname changes, the page still retains its previous scroll position after navigation, which is not the intended behavior.
I also wanna say that I have read every relevant post on the matter on Stack Overflow and nothing seems to work for me. I have tried every resource to try and solve this issue.
The other questions' answers do not work in my scenario.
App.js:
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.js";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.js";
import Widgets from "./components/widgets/Widgets.js";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import Currency from "./components/widgets/Currency.js";
import Timer from "./components/widgets/Timer.js";
import Weather from "./components/widgets/Weather.js";
import MainPage from "./components/MainPage.js";
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop.js";

function App() {
  const [isSidebarVisible, setIsSidebarVisible] = useState(true);

  const toggleSidebar = () => setIsSidebarVisible(!isSidebarVisible);

  const personalRef = useRef(null);
  const skillsRef = useRef(null);
  const workRef = useRef(null);
  const educationRef = useRef(null);
  const publicationsRef = useRef(null);

  const refs = {
    personal: personalRef,
    skills: skillsRef,
    work: workRef,
    education: educationRef,
    publications: publicationsRef,
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="flex min-h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <NavBar 
          isSidebarVisible={isSidebarVisible} 
          toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} 
          refs={refs}
        />
        <div
          className={`flex-1 flex flex-col transition-all duration-300 ${
            isSidebarVisible ? "ml-20" : "ml-0"
          }`}
        >
          <header className="flex justify-between items-center p-8 bg-gray-800 text-white fixed w-full top-0 left-0 z-30 transition-all duration-300">
            <h1
              className={`text-2xl transition-all duration-300 ${
                isSidebarVisible ? "ml-20" : "ml-0"
              }`}
            >
              Richard Lechko - IT Student @ DePaul University
            </h1>
            <button
              onClick={toggleSidebar}
              className="p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded"
            >
              {isSidebarVisible ? "Close Sidebar" : "Open Sidebar"}
            </button>
          </header>
          <main className="flex-1 flex flex-col pt-24 overflow-hidden">
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <MainPage
                    personalRef={personalRef}
                    skillsRef={skillsRef}
                    workRef={workRef}
                    educationRef={educationRef}
                    publicationsRef={publicationsRef}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
              <Route path="/widgets" element={<Widgets />} />
              <Route path="/widgets/currency" element={<Currency />} />
              <Route path="/widgets/timer" element={<Timer />} />
              <Route path="/widgets/weather" element={<Weather />} />
            </Routes>
            <Footer refs={refs} />
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

ScrollToTop.js:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ScrollToTop: Pathname changed to', pathname);
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
};

export default ScrollToTop;

NavBar.js:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  FaUser,
  FaTools,
  FaBriefcase,
  FaGraduationCap,
  FaBook,
  FaEnvelope,
} from "react-icons/fa";

const NavBar = ({ isSidebarVisible, refs, toggleSidebar }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const handleNavClick = (sectionId) => {
    if (refs[sectionId] && refs[sectionId].current) {
      refs[sectionId].current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    } else {
      navigate("/");
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (refs[sectionId] && refs[sectionId].current) {
          refs[sectionId].current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  };

  const handleExternalNavClick = (path) => {
    navigate(path, { replace: true });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`fixed top-0 h-screen ${
        isSidebarVisible ? "w-20" : "w-0"
      } bg-gray-900 text-white shadow-lg transition-all duration-300 z-40`}
    >
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <NavItem icon={<FaUser size={28} />} onClick={() => handleNavClick('personal')} />
          <NavItem icon={<FaTools size={28} />} onClick={() => handleNavClick('skills')} />
          <NavItem icon={<FaBriefcase size={28} />} onClick={() => handleNavClick('work')} />
          <NavItem icon={<FaGraduationCap size={28} />} onClick={() => handleNavClick('education')} />
          <NavItem icon={<FaBook size={28} />} onClick={() => handleNavClick('publications')} />
          <NavItem icon={<FaEnvelope size={28} />} onClick={() => handleExternalNavClick('/contact')} />
          <NavItem icon={<FaTools size={28} />} onClick={() => handleExternalNavClick('/widgets')} />
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

const NavItem = ({ icon, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <li onClick={onClick}>
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-4 hover:bg-gray-700 transition-colors cursor-pointer">
        {icon}
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default NavBar;


window.scrollTo(0,0) is invalid because your window dom itself can't scroll, you should try window.document.body.scrollTo(0,0)
